# Swift - didDeselectItemAtIndexPath returning wrong data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a nav bar button to load a slide in menu from the bottom that contains four items. Clicking on one of these menu items will open a new empty view.

Everything is working as intended, aside from one thing: **clicking a menu item currently opens a random view from my array of views**. Printing the indexPath to the console also shows that the array is being shuffled every time I return to the home screen after having launched a view. I even can't click the same item twice in a row (nothing happens when I do that).

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening, but I really have no idea what's going on.

**Why is my indexPath returning incorrect information from my array of menu items?**

```
class Setting: NSObject {

let name: SettingName
let imageName: String

init(name: SettingName, imageName: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.imageName = imageName
}
}

// Set list of items for menu
enum SettingName: String {
case Cancel = "Cancel"
case PostNews = "Post News"
case CheckLog = "Student Activity"
case AddStudent = "Add Student"
}

class MenuLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let blackView = UIView()

let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cv
}()

let cellId = "cellId"
let cellHeight: CGFloat = 50

let settings: [Setting] = {
    let newsSetting = Setting(name: .PostNews, imageName: "menu_postnews")
    let cancelSetting = Setting(name: .Cancel, imageName: "menu_cancel")

    return [newsSetting, Setting(name: .CheckLog, imageName: "menu_log"),
            Setting(name: .AddStudent, imageName: "menu_addstudent"), cancelSetting]
}()

var homeController: NewsController?

// Load menu
func openMenu() {

    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {

        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)

        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(settings.count) * cellHeight
        let y = window.frame.height - height
        collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, window.frame.width, height)

        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Dismiss menu when user touches the screen
func handleDismiss(setting: Setting) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.blackView.alpha = 0

        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height,
                self.collectionView.frame.width,
                self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }

    }) { (completed: Bool) in
        if setting.name != .Cancel {
            self.homeController?.showControllerForSetting(setting)
        }
    }
}

// Fill in the menu with all the items
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settings.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    let setting = settings[indexPath.item]
    cell.setting = setting

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width, cellHeight)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
    handleDismiss(setting)
    print(setting.name) // Is indexPath correct?
}

override init() {
    super.init()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
}
```

Comment: its `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` or `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` instead of `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` and your issue will be solved!

Comment: Oh guys, I have been looking at my code for a long time and I totally missed it! Thanks for the feedback :-) stupid me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Ketan Parmar** and **Anbu Karthik** mentioned: I picked the incorrect function parameters. I somehow wrote *didDeselectItemAtIndexPath* instead of *didSelectItemAtIndexPath*. Just a reminder to carefully check your code when implementing new functionalities. Thanks guys!

**My code**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
handleDismiss(setting)
print(setting.name) // Is indexPath correct?
```

}

**Correct code**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
handleDismiss(setting)
print(setting.name) // Is indexPath correct?
```

}